# Create a nested ordered list in a tabular style with css

Tags: html, css

Hi I am looking to display my ordered list this:
so the first node and the first nested node appear on the top line and the remaining nested nodes appear under the 2nd column (under red).

```
Apples    Red
          Green
          Yellow

Banana    Yellow
```

html:

```
<ul class="lst" id="list_Apple">
    <li>Apple</li> 
    <ul>
        <li id="Apple">Red</li>
        <li id="Apple">Green</li>
        <li id="Apple">Yellow</li>
    </ul>
</ul>

<ul class="lst" id="list_Banana">
    <li>Banana</li> 
    <ul>
        <li id="Banana">Yellow</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have to make some progress and ask for help once you face a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight mistake in your html. The `<ul>` tag should be inside a `<li>`.

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="lst" id="list_Apple">
    <li>Apple</li> 
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li id="Apple">Red</li>
            <li id="Apple">Green</li>
            <li id="Apple">Yellow</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="lst" id="list_Banana">
    <li>Banana</li> 
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li id="Banana">Yellow</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And add this **CSS**:

```
.lst {
    clear: both;
}

.lst li {
    list-style: none;
}

.lst > li {
    float: left;
}
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rayg8ua9/1/

Answer (score 0):

lithanks... Yes I missed the li tag.

```
.lst {
        clear: both;
        padding-top: 10px;
    }

.lst li {
        list-style: none;
        width:100px;
}

.lst > li {
        float: left;
}
```